# How do I make a command happen before another has ended?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I want a script that opens google chrome with different links with a 1 second delay.

So far I've got:

```py
print("I")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Told")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("You")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Not")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("To")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Run")
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
print("Me!")
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("google.com")
import webbrowser
import time
time.sleep(1)
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("google.com")
```

but it will open the first `google.com` in chrome then only open the next when I close the first so it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe look into multiprocess and spawn a process for each request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resume program (or exit) after opening webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149233/how-to-resume-program-or-exit-after-opening-webbrowser)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to repeatedly `import time` every time you call `time.sleep` - just one import at the start of your script is sufficient. Likewise for `import webbrowser`.

Comment: This behavior might be OS dependent. I tried a simple similar script to OP's and there, the call to `open` is _not_ blocking.

Comment: This isn't what you are asking for, but this function will run some code and wait.

`>>> def do_wait(op,arg,wait):
...     op(arg)
...     time.sleep(wait)

>>> cmd=sys.stdout.write
>>> arg='hello'
>>> wait=1
>>> do_wait(cmd,arg,wait)
hello <1-second-delay> >>>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised that you're having this issue: Here's a script that I just wrote that dutifully opens two new tabs one after the other without me having to close the originally created tab:

```py
import webbrowser

browser = webbrowser.get("firefox")

browser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com")
print("Opened that. What next?")
browser.open_new_tab("https://www.twitter.com")
print("Opened that too.")
```

Are you sure that you want to pass the full path to your browser into the `webbrowser.get` function? Try just passing in "chrome", the name for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping your `webbrowser.get()` code in an asynchronous function? Something like:

```
async def openBorwser(url):
    webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open(url)
```

And then from your main program, you can simply call:

```
openBrowser('google.com')
```

**Explanation:** `async` functions are functions that run "in parallel" to the main program, so that the program can move on with the next instruction without waiting for the function to finish execution.