# webbrowser doesn't open new tabs in Edge browser after having it registered

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I've pulled a script from [here](https://github.com/muckitymuck/rewardsgen) and I'm trying to modify it to open several URLs in new tabs in Edge. As long as I know the [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) doesn't have Edge as predefined so I had to register it.

This is the script:

```
import webbrowser
import time
import os

url = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=reddit'

webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(os.environ['ProgramFiles(x86)'] + r'\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'), preferred=True)
webbrowser.open_new(url)

fh = open('binggenlist.txt')
for line in fh:

    webbrowser.open(url+'+'+line)
    time.sleep(2)

fh.close()
```

The issue is that when I run this script a new Edge window is opened but new tabs are not. If I close the window opened a new one appears with the next line from the file in URL.
If Edge is already open when I run the script it works fine.

I've already tried to use other functions to open a new tab such as open_new_tab or open_new but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "webbrowser" module gets the control untill the brwoser is closed.
I think you could treat the situation as discussed in a previously answerd questioned at the followin link:
[How to resume program (or exit) after opening webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149233/how-to-resume-program-or-exit-after-opening-webbrowser)

Comment: so why this version of the script runs well?

`import webbrowser
import time

url = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=reddit'

webbrowser.open_new(url)

fh = open('binggenlist.txt')
for line in fh:

    webbrowser.open(url+'+'+line)
    time.sleep(2)

fh.close()`

Answer (score 0):

As your code works well in case of elminating the registration line,but offcourse the defualt browser will be used.
Therefore, I have tried your code but by using "msedge_proxy.exe" instead of "msedge.exe", and it works well now.

```
webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(os.environ['ProgramFiles(x86)'] + r'\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe'), preferred=True)
```

So the code after minor modification mentioned above is:

```
import webbrowser
import time
import os

url = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=reddit'

webbrowser.register('edge', None, webbrowser.GenericBrowser(os.environ['ProgramFiles(x86)'] + r'\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe'), preferred=True)
webbrowser.open(url)

fh = open('binggenlist.txt')
for line in fh:
    webbrowser.open(url+'+'+line, new=2)
    time.sleep(2)

fh.close()
```

Try it.

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks a lot, don't know why though :(

Comment: As you noticed it is seemed that msedge.exe does not send return resoponse imdeatly after begin executing, and. It send return "ok" back after closing, and  usually proxies comminucate better with other application, Therefore, I have tried to use proxy instead.