# Multiprocessing in Python Regarding Browser Pauses the Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run my code to open the Browser, the code Waits for the Browser to close and then the code continues.
For eg.

```
webbrowser.open_new("example.com")
sleep(10)
File = "chrome.exe"
f = wmi.WMI()
for process in f.Win32_Process():
    if process.name == File:
        process.Terminate()
        exit()
```

It should Close the browser after 10 Seconds, but I suppose the Program gets Paused, and waits until the Opened Program (Chrome) is close and if I Manually close the Browser and then it would Resume the Program.
How to FIX This?
According to this same question ([How to resume program (or exit) after opening webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149233/how-to-resume-program-or-exit-after-opening-webbrowser)) `os.fork()` should work. But it didn't work on mine, the person who gave this Answer also said that `os.fork` might not work on Windows.
What is its Alternative??

I have been Searching the Answer of this Question for a long time but no help. Would be great if somebody knows the FIX.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `async` functionality and let it run in the background, hence, not calling the `await` mechanism on it.

```
import asyncio

async def close_browser(process):
        process.Terminate()
        exit()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

webbrowser.open_new("example.com")
sleep(10)
File = "chrome.exe"
f = wmi.WMI()
for process in f.Win32_Process():
    if process.name == File:
        loop.create_task(close_browser(process))
```

Comment: not sure about whether runs or not, approach seems to be fine.. i guess

Comment: @kishore what do you say? have some tips/optimizations? :thinking_face:

Comment: Thank you very much, I am just starting out with Python, maybe its been about 1.5 Month, It would be helpful too if you could explain the Commands used.

Comment: Sure, closing the browser while the program keeps running. Classic `async` programming (Asynchronous programming is a type of parallel programming in which a unit of work is allowed to run separately from the primary application thread). In the code I've just made the function `close_browser` asynchronous by adding `async` before the `def` and called it in a way where the function won't block the run until it stops. I refer you to read more on async programming, specifically in python and also in general as well as reading on the event loop. Good luck! p.s. Please accept & upvote my answer:)